# What can the mother Maiamai upgrade?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

She mentions she can only upgrade items that I own. Given that I have to buy seemingly everything I want to use from Ravio, what can she upgrade? How many of her children do I have to save for the upgrades?

Comment: She can upgrade every item you buy from Ravio. She won't upgrade them so long as they're still rented, so you might want to buy them, even if you're confident that you won't ever die.

Comment: you need to save 90 for all the items to be upgraded. For the great spin attack, you need all 100 of them

Answer (score 5):

She can upgrade the Ice Rod, Fire Rod, Sand Rod, Boomerang, Bow, Bombs, Hookshot, Hammer, and the Tornado Rod every (10) Maiamai children you find.

Nice Fire Rod: Attack lasts longer and deals more damage: Return 10 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai

Nice Ice Rod: Creates 4 ice shards: Return 10 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai

Nice Sand Rod: Sand pillars last longer: Return 10 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai

Nice Boomerang: Fire up to three boomerangs with improved speed and range: Return 10 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai

Nice Tornado Rod: Wider range: Return 10 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai

Nice Mallet: Doubled range and damage: Return 10 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai

Nice Bow: Shoots three arrows at once: Return 10 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai

Nice Bombs: Wider range and more damage: Return 10 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai

Nice Hookshot: Faster and deals damage: Return 10 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai

Great Spin Attack: A wide-range spin attack: Return all 100 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai.

Nice Net: Deals 8x normal damage: Complete the Treacherous Tower’s Advanced Mode twice.

Nice Lantern: Deals 8x normal damage: Complete the Treacherous Tower’s Advanced Mode once

---

See more at: http://www.zeldainformer.com/walkthrough/page/item-upgrade-guide#sthash.SiUzp4Vk.dpuf

Comment: The Hookshot does not fire further or do more damage. It can always pull shields away. It merely goes faster and retracts faster. The Bomb's blast radius doubles, but the damage doesn't change. Not sure about the others, but the Sand Rod was never limited to one square of raising.

Comment: This information looks like you got it from somewhere - mind sharing where, as otherwise, it feels like it might be plagiarised, based on you not having experience with them?

Comment: The previous post I made (before editing) was my own and not plagiarised. I looked around for a complete list and posted it here with a link.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to all of the upgrades:[Item Upgrade Guide](http://www.zeldainformer.com/walkthrough/page/item-upgrade-guide)

> Nice Fire Rod: Attack lasts longer and deals more damage: Return 10 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai
>
> Nice Ice Rod: Creates 4 ice shards: Return 10 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai
>
> Nice Sand Rod: Sand pillars last longer: Return 10 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai
>
> Nice Boomerang: Fire up to three boomerangs with improved speed and range: Return 10 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai
>
> Nice Tornado Rod: Wider range: Return 10 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai
>
> Nice Mallet: Doubled range and damage: Return 10 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai
>
> Nice Bow: Shoots three arrows at once: Return 10 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai
>
> Nice Bombs: Wider range and more damage: Return 10 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai
>
> Nice Hookshot: Faster and deals damage: Return 10 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai
>
> Great Spin Attack: A wide-range spin attack: Return all 100 Maiamais to Mother Maiamai.